# Lua function returns 768 values - how to put these into a table

Tags: lua

I am programming an instrument that uses Lua with extensions for accessing the instrument controls and displays.

The instrument has a command to read the analyzer plotted points for frequency and amplitude:

*:analyzer:trace:frequency?*

and

*:analyzer:trace:amplitude?*

Whenever either of the above is executed, 768 values are returned (frequency or amplitude).  This is an embedded test system running Lua for user apps - I can't change the command.

I tried to use *table.pack()* to put these returned values into a table, but the syntax of the command with the ":" causes an error.

Code I tried --

*freq = {};*

*freq = table.pack(:analyzer:trace:frequency?);*

Error message is -- *tests.lua:2428: unexpected symbol near ':'*

Whenever the *:analyzer:trace:frequency?* is run stand alone (from PuTTY) or as a line in the Lua code, there is no error.

PuTTY receives 768 frequency values, each separated by a comma.

Looking for ways to direct the return into an array/table or to wrap the command so that it will execute similarly as above.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand the task but you can use `{...}` to pack, so `table = {yourFunction()}`

Comment: `:analyzer:trace:frequency?` **is not a Lua command**. You need to find what the Lua version of the command is

Comment: is there any reason why you say "an instrument" instead of simply naming the instrument and ideally linking a scripting reference? as others already mentioned :analzyer:trace:frequency? is not a Lua command. It looks more like a SCPI command. if you can run this by just having SCPI commands in a Lua script I would be surprised. is there no Lua function call involved? otherwise they would need some parser that can differe between Lua and SCPI statements

Comment: This is a SCPI command.  The instrument has a parser that added the SCPI  commands so that they are accessible in Lua.  My bad on calling this a Lua function.